# Regex for route work incorrect and return error 404

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have custom regex for match correct username:

```
^(?=.{5,20}$)[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Hp85x/1)

Here you can see my routes list:

```
Route::middleware(['userActivity'])->group(function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{nickname}','where' => ['nickname' => '^(?=.{5,20}$)[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$']], function ($nickname) {
        Route::name('user.')->namespace('User')->group(function () {            
            Route::middleware(['auth', 'company'])->group(function () {
                Route::namespace('Vacancy')->group( function () {
                    Route::prefix('vacancy')->name('vacancy.')->group( function () {
                        Route::get('/manage', "VacancyController@manage")->name('manage');
                        Route::post('/save', "VacancyController@save")->name('save');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In this case when I go to route `user.vacancy.manage`:

```
http://website.com/user_1544080981/vacancy/manage
```

Return error:

> 404 Page Not Found

When I change my regex to:

```
^(?=.{5,30}$)[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

**Note:** Changed in regex only min and max length from `{5,20}` to `{5,30}`

Generaly when I see to part of url after domain name url **length == 30**

```
user_1544081143/vacancy/manage
```

But regex must work **only for user nickname** instead of to part url without domain name. Where I have any errors in my routes?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @AlexMalikov Not, I haven't solve it.

Comment: I updated my answer you can use any for this

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression, this is a better way then above in my opinion.

```
  Route::any('{all}', function(){
    return 'It Works';
})->where('all', '.*');
```

Using the `Route::fallback` method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request. Typically, unhandled requests will automatically render a "**404**" page via your application's exception handler. However, since you may define the `fallback` route within your `routes/web.php` file, all middleware in the `web` middleware group will apply to the route. Of course, you are free to add additional middleware to this route as needed:

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```